# Spark compare two dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

- List item

Need to compare two dataframes and create a 3rd dataframe to generate the difference. 
While comparing the dataframes need to follow few conditions.

`DF1:(Struct type -> empid:IntegerType,name:StringType,phone:IntegerType)`

```
empid|name|phone
   1| amar | 12345
   2|  23  |<blank>
```

DF2: i am casting DF1 per their datatypes. `(col(c).cast(datatype))`

```
empid|name|phone
   1| amar | 12345
   2|  null  | null
```

Now here since name was string type it cast it to null. Also since phone was integer the blank was cast as null.

I need help to generate a third Dataframe,which should only point the casting error i had. If i consider all the null it takes the blank cast of phone as well which i dont want. Please see below example of expected DF3.

DF3:

```
empid|name|phone    |error
   1| amar | 12345  |null
   2|  23  |<blank> |name is wrong data type
```

Comment: looks like programmatically looking for "not-cassted" values is not the best approach. Maybe it would be better to write "correct" casting function and cover it with tests? You can do something like  `when(col("phone").isNull(), lit("NaN")).otherwise(col("phone").cast(datatype))`

Comment: Yes I am doing a data type validation here and that is done dynamically so can’t use it with the dataframe function

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what do you exactly mean by dynamic data type validatios. Could you pls bring an example of input and expected output?

Comment: I am doing a data type validation for a huge file . The schema is listed in a property file . So the validation is done dynamically for each row. Currently while doing casting it is converting the blank columns to null. As mentioned in my question above. Can you help on how to proceed given my example

Comment: why do you have two dataframes than? Are you creating another dataframe for sake of validation schema? What is the purpose of that validations? Do you want to drop mailformed records or map /handle them  in different way or convert them to schema?